# Take some strings plus date and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to fix a script for seo-friendly url and it is almost working but my brain is almost dead trying to understand why I get the wrong value in MySQL

The script uses the following values to prepare the variables to be inserted:

```
$date=date("Ymd");
$newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);
$urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);
$newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
```

Nothing strange with that, but now I am fixing the following variable to prepare the mysqli insert and this is the one with problem:

```
$url='news/'.$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'';
```

To submit the query I use the following code:

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into blog(title,body,url) 
values('$title','$body','$url')");
}
```

The result saved in MySQL should be something like this:

```
news/20221021/this-is-an-example-url
```

But the result I get saved in MySQL is this:

```
news/.$date./.$newurltitle.
```

So the values are not passing, I tried using $url='news/'$date.'/'$newurltitle.''; and $url='news/'.$date'/'.$newurltitle''; but no one of them will work. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Given the little code in your question, taken out of context, I cannot explain this result. You can either update your question, to contain a more complete version of your code, see: ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or you can insert an `echo $url;` before your query and see what its content it.

Comment: I'm almost sure about that you don't have literally `$url='news/'.$date.'/'.$newurltitle.'';` as you wrote in your question.

Comment: I tested with $url='news/.$date./.$newurltitle.'; and the same problem

Comment: @NovoMannen That's the WRONG thing, as I said in my answer. That's what will produce the result you got.

Comment: I can understand that you are happy now that your problem is solved. But your question still makes little sense. Can you edit it so it does? The reason for this is that other people will use your question to solve their own problems, just like you undoubtedly have already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain the result you're getting if the code you posted is accurate. You'd get that result if you wrote

```
$url = 'news/.$date./.$newurltitle.';
```

because variables are not expanded inside single quotes. However, you can write that simply using double quotes.

```
$url = "news/$date/$newurltitle";
```

Comment: Double quotes seems to work fine :) is there any other way ?

Comment: What you showed in the question should have worked. There's no need for `.''` at the end. I see it often in questions, no one can ever explain why they do it.